# Punching bag training kicks/punches

Tags: training, tae-kwon-do, kicking, muay-thai

Since sport club are closed, I would like to get some suggestion for training on my punching bag.

I would like something that trains the whole body since I was practicing Muay Thaï and Taekwondo, but with a bit more of kicking practice. But it is hard for me to practice Taekwondo tricky kicks with bag, so I want to improve in power and precision, and learn easy and effectives combo that I can apply against opponents.

What exercises/combos can you suggest for me? And what about training/rest timing?

Comment: This might fall under opinion-based questions, as it's very open-ended. There are a ton of different combos. And why are you having difficulties with three tricky kicks? Are you being thrown off balance on impact? Having trouble adjusting to the different profile of the bag?

Comment: While I was doing TKD, I'd say I got the most out of those blue-blocker shields that people used. And hand pads. You need a partner who sets it up at the right angle and can move around. The punching bag, for me, was mostly used for power and conditioning. To a lesser degree, combos. I liked a partner for practicing combos and precision more than a punching bag. You do aerobic conditioning more with a partner, too. With a punching bag, anaerobic.

Comment: yeah the blue shield are definitely so efficient to improve ! 

Yes it's like the harder I hit the bag (with tricky kicks), the less I keep in balance. And that doesn't happen when I hit people.

Answer (score 2):

Cut kicks are great, as well as all sorts of spin kicks, back kick, etc because it helps with upper body control and balance. I actually don't know what this is called, but the kicks where you kick low and then high, and repeat. Cutkicks and pi chagi with a hand against the wall, 30 on each side 5 reps is also good. The most important one is step back counter (step back, back leg pi chagi) as well as cut kick -> hook kick, that's my personal favorite. anything that starts with cut kick is good. focus on speed. foot placement. and goodluck.